# How to roll back to the previous state in Firebase RealtimeDB for Android, when a nested ValueEventListener for SingleValueEvent or Transaction fails?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a Java and `Firebase` based native Android app that requires multiple writes (using `SingleValueEventListener` or Transaction) to different Realtime DB references based on certain actions.
It's something like:

1. User clicks a button.
2. In a SingleValueEventListener1/Transaction1 for DB ref 1, DB reference 1 gets updated.
3. Once DB ref 1 gets updated successfully, in another SingleValueEventListener2/Transaction2 nested within SingleValueEventListener1/Transaction1, DB reference 2 starts to update.
   ...and so on.

> **What do I need?**

Update a second DB location, only after the first location I am trying to update is successful. The locations facilitate concurrent updates.

**Preliminary research:**

I have looked at various posts and stack overflow questions on DB rollback, concurrent updates, multi-location updates, databases rules and security, but none of them have helped my cause.

**What are some of the resources that I have looked at?**

[Firebase undoable update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36096698/firebase-right-way-to-implement-an-undoable-update), [Firebase commit rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387419/firebase-commit-rollback-for-complex-writes), [Firebase multi-write](https://github.com/katowulf/firebase-multi-write), [Firebase multi-location updates](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html)

**What is the problem?**

There is no problem in the updating of references. the problem lies in the fact that if DB reference 1 is updated successfully, and DB reference 2 update fails, then I have no option to roll back Ref 1 to the previous state.

**Is this approach required?**

In my case, unfortunately yes.

**What are some of the options to solve this?**

1. I can store the previous state of Ref 1 and if an update fails for Ref 2, I can rewrite the previous state at Ref 1.
   But these locations support concurrent updates, and by the time I roll back to a previous state, the previous state too might have been updated. The previous data may become stale and overriding the ref with that data might cause loss of data. Solving all these call for undesired complexities in code that might not guarantee solving the problem at all.
2. Transactions would definitely try to update Ref 2 until successful, but until a certain time, and may be the failure to write at a second location is caused due to a loss in network connectivity, which explains a part of my concern.
3. Another option is changing the DB design and moving all the multiple DB references to one single location, so that if the location update fails, nothing changes as per Firebase. However, the way I have designed the database seems to be fine. In fact, to facilitate the removal of this problem, if I change my database structure, and shift things to one-single location, it would be absolutely wrong in my case. To explain this with a similar situation, for example, in StackOverflow, if I upvote an answer, the reputation of the person who answered changes, the status of the answer changes with respect to the people involved and the number of votes, the activity of the person who upvoted changes and may be his reputation as well. Now all of the above DB refs cannot be merged into a single one.

*The problem is independent of SingleValueEventListeners or Transactions.*

**A simple code example of the case, for which the problem came up?**

This following illustrates a 2-level deep nested EventListeners (the same is applicable for Transactions as well), for simplicity.

```
ValueEventListener outerListener = new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
    //do something
    //update DBRefOne
    DBRefOne.updateChildren(newOuterValue, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
      @Override
      public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
        ValueEventListener innerListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
          //do something
          //update DBRefTwo
          DBRefTwo.updateChildren(newInnerValue);
          }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
       // log error
      }
    };
    DBRefTwo.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(innerListener);
   }
 });
}
}
  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
  // log error
  }
};
DBRefOne.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(outerListener);
```

This is a non-trivial but tricky problem for me, that needs to be solved, as most of the app is done otherwise. I am willing to rework based on your suggestions. Please feel free to suggest, any help is more than appreciated with humility and gratitude.

Comment: I wrote a quick answer on your options below. I appreciate that you tried to be thorough in your question, but that makes it quite a lot of work to parse. I recommend editing to just focus on the [minimal code + JSON that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). E.g. in your current code snippet, we can't know how `DBRefOne` and `DBRefTwo` are related, nor what `newOuterValue` and `newInnerValue` are (based on).

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to update data transactionally:

1. Use a transaction
2. Use a multi-location update

There is no hidden third way, so if you want to update data transactionally, you will have to use one of these.

If the values you write are not based on the current values, you should use a multi-location update, since it has much better performance characteristics. For more on this, read this blog post: [Client-side fan-out for data consistency](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html).

If the values you write is based on the current value(s), you need to use a transaction. In that case it is important to ensure the data you're writing is all close to each other in the JSON, since you're effectively placing a (optimistic) lock on the top of the location you update.

Comment: Thanks for your response. i will keep your advise handy for future posts. However, following up on your response for transactions (as my values are based on current values), I still have to ask you, what happens when the outer transaction is successful and once it completes, the nested inner transaction starts to execute, but it fails - how to recover the prev value of outer transaction, storing it isnt an option as it may be updated by then? Transactions try many times, but stop after a point. Its an edge case, but a valid one. What are your views on that, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: There is no nesting of transactions.You'll have to do the updates in a single transaction, which means you have to run that transaction at the lowest level in the JSON where you can get both values. The higher up in the tree that is, the worse your transaction will perform.